# Why Container does not run when I create a VOLUME?

Tags: docker

I'm new using dockers and trying to create a volume between Windows directory and Debian Container.

although the dockerfile does not have WORKDIR, I decided use default path inside container, for example, `/home/` or `/`, whatever folder, path.

Is necessary create a WORKDIR to use VOLUME? I think no! what I need to do?

`docker run --rm -v %echo%:/home/ --name rust_container rust`

dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/usr/local/rustup \
    CARGO_HOME=/usr/local/cargo \
    PATH=/usr/local/cargo/bin:$PATH

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        gcc \
        libc6-dev \
        wget \
        ; \
    \
    url="https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init"; \
    wget "$url"; \
    chmod +x rustup-init; \
    ./rustup-init -y --no-modify-path --default-toolchain nightly; \
    rm rustup-init; \
    chmod -R a+w $RUSTUP_HOME $CARGO_HOME; \
    rustup --version; \
    cargo --version; \
    rustc --version; \
    \
    apt-get remove -y --auto-remove \
        wget \
        ; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to set the workdir to use a volume, the workdir will default to the root folder. The directory you reference in the -v argument needs to exist in the container folder structure though because you are mounting a volume. So if /home/ doesn’t exist there is nothing for the volume to mount to. If you include a host point like /foo/bar:/home you will create a bind mount not a volume which mounts the host file system directory inside the container.

Comment: agree, but even I indicating a existing folder `/home/`, however it didnt work!